# CSS 'Transform: rotate' on Page Load using Jquery/Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

Simple div to display a speedometer;

```
 <div class="outer">
   <div class="needle" ></div>
 </div>
```

On hover the speedometer animates fine;

```
.outer:hover .needle {
  transform: rotate(313deg); 
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

I need this to animate on page load, hence I tried changin the class name from `.outer:hover .needle` to `.animateNow` and used the following jquery to add this to `.circle`;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.outer').addClass('animateNow');
});
```

That didn't work, any ideas?

Full CSS;

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color: black;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
    height:100vw;
    width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../CentreDial3.png);
    background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.needle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 3s ease-in;

}
.needle:before {

  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  height: 45%;
  width: 5px;
background: #b30000;
    border-radius: 40%;

}
.needle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  left: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  border-top: 0px solid white;
  border-left: 0px solid black;


}


.outer:hover .needle,
 .outer.animateNow .needle{
  transform: rotate(313deg); 
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried @keyframes animation?

Comment: Your jquery would not add class because of you use dot before class in your jquery. Please remove dot before class name.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I have tried, coudn't get it to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly note that when calling `addClass()` in jQuery you need to omit the `.` selector, so your code should be:

```
$('.circle').addClass('animateNow');
```

Then to make the animation work when you add the class you just need to amend the CSS to work on both hover and when the `.circle` element has that class.

Note that you will need to add the class either on `window.load` or after a small delay using `setTimeout()`, otherwise it will be immediately shown in its final position. Try  this:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.outer').addClass('animateNow');
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../CentreDial3.png);
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.needle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 3s ease-in;
}

.needle:before {
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  height: 45%;
  width: 5px;
  background: #b30000;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.needle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  left: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  border-top: 0px solid white;
  border-left: 0px solid black;
}

.outer:hover .needle,
.outer.animateNow .needle {
  transform: rotate(313deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="needle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work, the hover now has no effect on the div and no animation takes place on load.

Comment: @ArraysRus could you please edit your question to show your full HTML and CSS. It's hard to visualise the issue when you can't see it working.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I can't see why that would be the case given the OP's original has no sibling operator

Comment: My mistake, hover works, the on page load animation wont load, i'm adding full css into question for clarity.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Ah yes, you're right - although that was a typo on the OPs part.

Comment: I know the rules are we shouldn't say thanks, but thanks guys, was pulling my hair out!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)